# Can't find exact match in OS type when creating new VM in VMware Workstation

Tags: installation, operating-systems, vmware-workstation

When creating a new VM, I sometimes can't find an exact match for the OS I am installing, usually a Linux. For example I was installing Kali but VMware doesn't have the option so I guess it should be the newest Debian because Kali is derrived? What difference does it make and how can I avoid any potential problems? Some of the options given in VMware are strange, like what's Asanux under Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What difference does it make and how can I avoid any potential problems?

This question is asked so that the Vm can be set up with the hardware best supported by the OS. Other than that it does not seem to make any difference.

E.g. installing win98 (yes old) and:

- I select Linux. Vmware offers a SCSI card be default. Win98 does not have the drivers and I need to add then.
- I choose win98 - Vmware offers a hardware configuration with an IDE controller by default. No additional driver needed.

Or when installing Linux:

- Select linux and get offered an emulated SCSI card (and all advantages of SCSI such as tagged queue's).
- Select windows and Linux still works.

That makes it more an ease of use and possibly a slight performance gain issue and not something which you **must** choose. As such a close match will do fine.

Comment: I think it may be helpful to VMware to know the guest OS so that it can try to install VMware tools automatically, thought this isn't a big deal as it can be manually installed. https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003912

Comment: Ah. Right. I mostly forgot about that since I always had to do that manually with guest OS FReeBSD.